# Creating a .jar assistance

Tags: java, android, jar

I am working on creating an Android app and need to import a jar containing a class that I created into it, the class doesn't contain a main method, so, as far as I understand, the jar won't be executable, which is fine. I just need it to be able to be used within the application.

How do I create the jar file?

Comment: You mean you don't know how to _create_ the jar or you don't know how to add the jar dependency?

Comment: Both, I suppose. But let's start with the jar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating by using command prompt: `jar cvf jar-file-name folder-of-classes`

Steps to do:

```
    1) Take all the required `.class` files place it into a folder named `xyz`in directory `D:\abc` 
    2) Open Command prompt and change the current working directory to D:\abc
    3) run command as jar cvf test.jar xyz
```

check the directory D:\abc there will be a jar file named test.jar containing the folder with all the class files.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

jar file is just a bunch of .class file. select your android package  Right click -> New -> Java Class. 
copy your old class file code into newly created. Do care class name & .class file be same name.

if you mean to import java .jar dependency 
Select your app. Right click goto New->Module->import .jar/.aar package

Comment: Couldn't I just create the jar file and drag and drop it into a libs folder? If that's the case, then all I need to know how to do is how to create the jar.

Comment: jar cvf Count.jar Count.class   This creates the count.jar file which could be used for later.

Comment: Could I create the jar by placing the .class of my class into the /bin folder of my java sdk? And then running your command with myclass.class as the input file?

Comment: you need to put this into your cmd (for windows) , terminal (for Linux).  Replace Count.jar(where to be generated) & Count.class(file location where it is)it will generate jar which could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jar file in your application
In your applications Android.mk; specify the name of the JAR file under the LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES :=